# Can an atomic nucleus contain both particles and antiparticles?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter

Is it theoretically possible to make a "deuterium" atom containing a proton and an antineutron in its nucleus?

Would the strong nuclear force cause attraction between a proton and an antineutron?

Would such a nucleus be stable, or would the proton somehow annihilate the antineutron when close enough?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation) has some info on annihilation reactions between nucleons & antinucleons, as I mention in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451337/123208).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An antineutron ($\bar{u}\bar{d}\bar{d}$) is made up of antiquarks and these will annihilate with the quarks in the proton ($uud$).

Such a nucleus is therefore unstable.

Comment: That does look like the most likely fate of such a system. The remaining $\bar d$ and $u$ quarks would then likely form a $\pi^+$ pion, which would eventually decay to an antimuon and then a positron.

Comment: N.B. from the links in the duplicates, it appears that there _are_ short-lived $p\bar{n}$ and $\bar{p}n$ bound states, so the answer to "Would the strong force cause attraction ..." is yes.